# Draw in a NSView using async/await

Tags: swift, macos, async-await, drawrect

Requesting guidance to use threading in drawing lines and circles on an NSView using threads. Below is the code structure I am using and getting the context error.

```
override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {

    Task {
        await plotYAxis()
    }

}

func plotYAxis() async {
    //Code to draw lines and labels
    ...
    ...
}
```

Below is the error --

**CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.

...

...

...

...**

Comment: The current graphics context is set per-thread, and should probably only ever be accessed via the main thread. Is there a particular reason you need to call an async function in your `draw` method? I don't think that makes much sense. If you're waiting on some data, you'll want to draw _something_ (e.g. a loading indicator), and redraw the loaded content once it's available.

Comment: As the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview/1483686-draw) says, “Use this method to draw the specified portion of your view’s content. Your implementation of this method should be as fast as possible and do as little work as possible.” It is not for launching some asynchronous process, but rather for quickly rendering a single frame (and sometimes only a small portion of the overall view). In short, do not use `async`. The graphics context is no longer valid once you return from `draw`.

Comment: @Alexander Thank you Alexander for your guidance, I was trying to animate the lines and circles within the view and therefore was exploring threading as I am new to swift and learning programming. Looks like I have to perform those calculations in async loop from outside of the view class and call needdisplay function. Thank you for your time!

Comment: @Rob Thank you Rob for providing the details. I am new to swift and learning programming, therefore, stumbling upon these basics. Thank you for your time and guidance.

Comment: No worries. We’ve all been there…